# Mac does not recognize wide screen

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, osx-lion, mac-mini

I am using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 on my Mac mini, with Samsung monitor with default resolution 1360 x 768.

My Mac mini is connected to Samsung VGA port by Apple mini port to VGA adapter.

When starting, my Mac does not recognize the wide screen resolution and always starts in a 4:3 mode, (but it shows 1360x768 as the resolution in the settings). I have to do one of the following actions to bring my Mac to the wide screen resolution:

(1) Changing to some other resolution and bring back to the default resolution.

(2) Unplug the Apple mini port to VGA adapter and re-connect again.

(3) Put the machine to sleep and wake it up again.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, (in a different partition) in the same hardware, but Ubuntu is perfectly recognizing the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do the same thing.

1. Go to your system preferences (clink on the apple icon the in top left of the bar)
2. Click on Display (under hardware section - 2nd from top)
3. There you can choose the the option that matches your monitor

If that dosent work, then you might want to contact the manufacture to see if they have a disk for insulation or a support system that can assist you with the error.